# detect the the title bar height for a window for different operating systems with javascript

Tags: javascript, operating-system, window, google-chrome-app

I am making a canvas game in a chrome app with it's own window. I made my game resize with the window's size using `window.onResize`. Since my game is made with an 8-bit style, I don't want the default window size to have blurry pixels because it is partially resized.

I am aware that you can specify the window's size in the `background.js` file, but when the window opens, the size of the window includes the title bar.

[image]

Basically, I want the game height to be 400px, but I can only set the window height. The title bar is included in the window height, so different operating systems with different title bar heights will affect the size of the game height. I need a way to detect the height of the operating systems title bar height in `background.js`.

Comment: Is this windows just the window of the browser on the OS?

Comment: The window is it's own chrome window with no tabs or search bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fully control window size of the app create a frameless window that won't have any built-in decorations, draw everything yourself.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create("window.html", {  
         frame: "none",
         .............
    });
});
```

[`chrome.app.window` API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) provides [a sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window), here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately this api is now deprecated. Do you have any alternate suggestions to get a frameless window/get the height of the window title bar? Thanks!