# How to remove all margin and padding from my Google Chrome packaged app content?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

[This page says](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) (in three places):

> Note that the padding between the inner and outer bounds is determined by the OS.

I want to remove all padding and margins from the bounds of my Chrome App (f/k/a Google Chrome Packaged App). In some circles, this effect is known as ***fullbleed***. In other words, I want the content to touch all the edges of the screen or viewport.

**How do I accomplish this? Or is it impossible?**

Note: My below hack of using negative margins and padding in the style attribute is just that. A hack. But if you can't give me a proper solution, I'll take a hack that works better than the one I have so far.

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'outerBounds': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 500,
        },
        'state': 'fullscreen'
    });
});
```

window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: -15px; padding: -15px">
        <webview src="http://www.google.com/"
                 style="width:100vw; height:100vh">
        </webview>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [detect the the title bar height for a window for different operating systems with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33741035)

Answer (score 2):

window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <webview src="http://www.google.com/"></webview>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could write `0` instead of `0px`.